# Query/Update Spring 3 Scheduled task cron expression

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I have a scheduled job configured in an XML file:

```
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="taskScheduler">
  <task:scheduled ref="scheduledJobs" method="doSomething" cron="30 * * * * ?"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>

<bean id="scheduledJobs" class="com.xxx.ScheduledJobs"/>

<task:scheduler id="taskScheduler" pool-size="2" />
```

Is it possible to query the cron expression (to display to the user) and update it (not necessarily in the XML file but in the bean instance) with a new cron expression?

Or is there a better way of achieving this type of functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer is this is not possible using Spring/JDK scheduling but is possible if you use Quartz scheduling instead:

There is another thread covering a similar area:

[Rescheduling a CronTriggerBean dynamically with same job details in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778625/rescheduling-a-crontriggerbean-dynamically-with-same-job-details-in-spring)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in a programmatic way, shortened version:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler;
import org.springframework.scheduling.TriggerContext;
import org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronTrigger;

public class ChangelogDeleterTask implements InitializingBean, Runnable {

    @Autowired
    private TaskScheduler scheduler;
    private ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledTask;
    private CronTrigger trigger;
    private Date nextExecutionTime;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    schedule("0/5 * * * * *");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {/*do scheduled job*/}

    public synchronized void schedule(String cronExpression) {
    scheduledTask.cancel(false);
    trigger = new MyCronTrigger(cronExpression);
    scheduledTask = scheduler.schedule(this, trigger);
    }

    String getNextExecutionTime() {
    return nextExecutionTime.toString();
    }

    String getExpression() {
    return trigger.getExpression();
    }

    /**
     * Class allows to remember nextExecutionTime.
     */
    private class MyCronTrigger extends CronTrigger {
    public ChangelogCronTrigger(String expression) {
        super(expression);
    }

    @Override
    public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
        Date date = super.nextExecutionTime(triggerContext);
        nextExecutionTime = new Date(date.getTime());
        return date;
    }
    }
}
```